# Mockk verification of deep stubs fail

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockk

Kotlin version: 1.5 - Mockk version 1.12.0

I know that every time a mock returns a mock we are somehow violating the Law of Demeter. In my app I'm using RedisTemplate which for every operation its delegating to another object like

```
redisTemplate.opsForSet().members()
```

or

```
redisTemplate.opsForSet().remove()
```

In these cases I have to mock a mock. Long story short I tried to simplify by an example as below:

```kotlin
interface Action {
  fun send(): Int
  fun getSteps(): List<Int>
}

class Notifier(val action: Action) {}

class Rabbit {
  fun jump(steps: Int): Boolean {
    return if (steps % 2 == 0) {
      println("Jumping $steps steps .... ")
      true
    } else {
      println("Dont want to jump!")
      false
    }
  }
}

class Service(
    private val rabbit: Rabbit,
    private val notifier: Notifier,
) {

  fun play() {
    for (steps in notifier.action.getSteps()) {
      val jumped = rabbit.jump(steps)
      if (jumped) {
        notifier.action.send()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My test class is as below:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
class ServiceTest {
  @MockK private lateinit var rabbit: Rabbit
  @MockK private lateinit var notifier: Notifier

  @InjectMockKs private lateinit var service: Service

  @Test
  fun `One notification should be sent`() {
    every { notifier.action.getSteps() } returns listOf(1, 2, 3)
    every { rabbit.jump(1) } returns false
    every { rabbit.jump(2) } returns false
    every { rabbit.jump(3) } returns true
    every { notifier.action.send() } returns 1

    service.play()

    verify(exactly = 3) { rabbit.jump(any()) }
    verify(exactly = 1) { notifier.action.send() }
  }
```

The problem is every time I run this test it fails with the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 2: Notifier(notifier#1).getAction()). 2 matching calls found, but needs at least 1 and at most 1 calls
Calls:
1) Notifier(notifier#1).getAction()
2) Notifier(notifier#1).getAction()
```

I know that Mockk is able to handle [chain calls](https://mockk.io/#chained-calls) but I cannot understand what is the issue. Any thoughts?